# split one tty verticaly

Tags: bash, display, tty

To see more from the command line history I came up with the idea to split the working-tty vertically. The working area would be on the right bottom corner of the window and the oldest visible command on the left top corner. So far I could not make it with screen? Is screen a possible tool for splitting one tty?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use screen to do vertical and horizontal splits. I recommend you to use [byobu](http://byobu.co/)

Here are some useful stuff for byobu:

Shift + F2: Horizontal split
Ctrl + F2: Vertical split
F2: New tab

Comment: I don't use `byobu` but I use sole `tmux` and I know basics of plain `screen`. I suspect the splitting you're talking about spawns a new shell session, so the two halves show independent shells (this is not what the OP wants). But I'm not sure. Please post a screenshot with a layout described in the question and I will gladly upvote your answer.